# Comparing NULL with INT

Tags: mysql, null

I am trying to pull all rows where two fields don't match.  I understand that nulls are essentially "unknowns" and so have taken steps to define nulls as 0's.  As below.

```
Select ifnull(field1, 0), ifnull(field2, 0) 
from table
where field1 != field2
```

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?  I still get no results even though i feel i am defining nulls as "0" with ifnull(field1, 0) correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because that is how `NULL` values work in relational databases.  Almost all comparisons return `NULL`, which is treated as false.

Also, what you do in the `SELECT` has no impact on the `WHERE`.  The fields are still coming from the original table.

More importantly is what you can do.  The simplest method is to use a `NULL`-safe comparison:

```
where not field1 <=> field2
```

Comment: I like this comparison, first time to see it to be honest

Comment: Thanks - i found this solution this morning but it didnt work.  Obviously i did something wrong then too!  This is a great solution and has cleared up my understanding!  Thanks again.

Comment: @mrateb . . . The ANSI standard operator would be `IS DISTINCT FROM`.

Answer (score 0):

Because 0 is inserted after and not before you select

Should be instead:

```
Select * from 
((Select *,ifnull(field1, 0) new_field1, ifnull(field2, 0) new_field2
from table) As query)
WHERE new_field1 != new_field2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the IFNULL() down to the WHERE clause like this:

```
Select ifnull(field1,0) as 'Field1', ifnull(field2, 0) as 'Field2'
from table
where ifnull(field1,0) != ifnull(field2,0)
```

Comment: When selecting ifnull() you're only "rewriting" the results with it. - It doesn't last into the WHERE clause. - That's why you should do it in the WHERE clause instead. I've done it both in the SELECT and WHERE clause, for you to see what it really compares now. :-)